# Is there a way an asker can start another thread from their old questions?

Tags: discussion

I have seen that a lot of people submit questions, and problems just keep coming up. Is there a way so that they could continue another thread, based on an old question?

Because seeing that they have to create another question with the same content and same code, it might lead to redundant data and also harder for other people to follow up on. Maybe an old solution is the one which causes the newer error or something like that.

I think it could be like this:

```
Old question code and information
---
Accepted answer
```

---

```
New issue or error, addition code and addition information also here
```

I think it will better if we can have this feature. Not only for questioners, but also for askers.

Comment: If the question basically requires same code, and problems just keep coming up, then probably those questions probably lack proper [mcve]. I don't see the need for such feature. If there is legitimate, good question that is somehow related to the old one it is easy to add link into question as reference.

Comment: So you are asking Stack Exchange to become more forum-like?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, not really. I've answer some questions and see that problem so just thinking out loud. Maybe I just give those question a downvote and comment to request them to give old question url instead of create new one with almost the same content.

Comment: And with this, answers might not need to switch between pages to get the context or something, just paste the link into the post and all the important information of old question will be rendered. But yeah, never mind.. I think just need a url is good enough, and questioner should make their question be a good question so they shouldn't replicas the question content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In reference to the earlier question: [Is there any way asker can start another thread from their old questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389900/is-there-any-way-asker-can-start-another-thread-from-their-old-questions)

Surely you can just use a hyperlink (like above) to reference the question to make a new fork of the question. Why would you need a new feature?

Answer (score 7):

The recommended way is simply to ask a new question referencing the original question if necessary by linking to it, describing how the new question differs from the original.

All the content doesn't need to be copied, only that relevant to the new question. Each question needs just enough to stand on its own.

That way all answers belong to the question they answer.